# git default editor on Windows 10

Tags: windows, git, editor, default

I just download and installed git on Windows 10. When I enter `git config --global --edit` it opens file in some editor, which I do not know how it is called. How can I find out? There are tons of links explaining how to change it, but they do not say what I already have as default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I remember correctly, the default editor is Vim, ESC + Shift ZZ to close.

Comment: It looks so. I also tried `ESC + :x + enter` and it worked

Answer (score 1):

try to use
git config --system --edit
its give you the link to the default editor for me it gives
[core]
    editor = "\"C:\\Program Files\\Notepad++\\notepad++.exe\" "

Comment: so you can add the link of the editor you want to use.